# RavenDB - concurrency exception without optimistic concurrency

Tags: ravendb, optimistic-concurrency

In our Raven DB instance, we periodically get concurrency exceptions. This has always puzzled me since we haven't enabled optimistic concurrency.

Google tells me that [there is a scenario](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/Qm7LGji1N2c) where concurrency exceptions can be thrown without optimistic concurrency enabled - where you have an index which calls LoadDocument() on a document of that type. This is indeed the case with our codebase.

However, the thread I just linked to does not suggest a remedial action. What should I do in when a concurrency exception occurs? Should retry logic work? Or should I do something else?

Answer (score 0):

A concurrency exception is raised if 2 threads are racing to physically modify the same document at the same time. One thread wins, the other(s) receives a concurrency exception.

It is up to you to determine what to do with that scenario.

Choices of what you *can* do:

1. **Nothing**. Unhandled exception. No different than if the network dropped for a minute
2. **Replay**.  Last in wins. Your document that errored was the last in, replay the request to overwrite all changes.
3. **Notify**. Trap the exception. Inform the user their request was not successful and for them to review their changes vs the current version of the document.
4. **Merge**. Diff the two documents, merge them together ala source control auto-merge
5. **Hand merge**. Present UI to the user that showcases both documents and allows the user to execute a 3-way merge

You could also build an intelligent system for doing this. Concurrency exception, attempt auto-merge, if good, all good. Auto-merge fails, return with notification to user "sorry we could not accept your changes, click here to compare your changes".

Comment: I understand what a concurrency exception is, although I'm a little surprised to receive any when I don't have optmistic concurrency enabled. (I say 'surprised', I think I mean 'irritated'.)

Comment: But what options do I have other than swallowing the exception to prevent the application breaking? I don't know the content of the two document versions, as I do in the case of a conflict.

Comment: From what I recall, with concurrency exceptions you don't see the two versions of the document - unlike with conflicts.

Comment: @David to see the other version (which is the currently persisted version) of the document you need to load the document in a separate session or in a session-less manner. The only time this would be useful for anything is if you're going to attempt to auto-merge or present a 3-way merge UI for the user.